# How to filter elements to be displayed from a has_many association in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oop, has-many

Say I have 3 nested models through has_many association:

```
class Map
  has_many :countries
end

class Country
  has_many :cities
  belongs_to :map
end

class City
  belongs_to :country
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I have a view that show the maps -> countries -> cities through the MapsController, that's fine.

Now city has a :published attribute and I would like to filter that view to *only* cities that are published + unpublished and user == current_user.

I tried to assign the has_many association with the filtered objects, but the problem with this approach is that autosave will delete the objects that don't match the criteria.

I could filter the cities in the view, with a city scope and this pseudo code in the view:

```
@map.countries.each do |country|
  country.cities_published_and_unpublished_by_user(current_user).each do |country|
    display country
  end
end
```

But it doesn't smell very good. Specially that in the future I'll might want to add more decisions and I believe these belong to the controller.

I'm sure there is a pattern I'm missing... any hints?

Comment: what Rails version?

Comment: @Jay-ArPolidario, is rails 5... but this is more a design question...

Comment: Yes this is indeed a design question, although the code I'm thinking of answering could change... (particularly that in Rails 5, you can now do the `.or(...)` query, which will be what you'll probably need to do the OR condition between "published" and "unpublished + belongs_to current_user"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At your controller 
your_condition depends on how many possible values have you for :published

```
@cities = current_user.cities.where(your_condition)
```

For example

```
@cities = current_user.cities.where({published: ["published", "unpublished"]})
```

at your view

```
<% @cities.each do |c| %>
  # your code to show each city
  c
<% end %>
```

Comment: similar answer as @denis ... I was looking for a more elegant solution that would allow me to navigate the map object without having to create new intermediate collections... but I believe is not possible

Comment: current_user.cities is a more accurate way to get your cities since your cities table has a relation with User, so you won't have to search through map, country, and cities, you only find in city table all the records that match with the user id.

Comment: Thanks, I'll follow your advise

Answer (score 0):

Try this additional relation.

```
class Map
  has_many :countries
  has_many :cities, through: countries
end

class Country
  has_many :cities
  belongs_to :map
end

class City
  belongs_to :country
  belongs_to :user
end
```

And you can now call:

```
@cities = @map.cities.where(user: current_user)
```

And in the view:

```
@cities.each(&:display)
```

Now to show published/unpublished items you can use scopes or default scope on cities model.

Comment: I thought on this ... although @cities will have an array of cities and I need to group them by country as well. Eventually I'll probably go with this solution I believe

Comment: @cities would be an ActiveRecord item, so you can do smth like @cities.group(:country_id) for grouping.

Comment: Sorry had to accept Oscar answer because he post it first and they are pretty much the same. Thanks for your help anyways!